# Processing keyPressed()

Tags: listener, processing, key

basically I have to use Processing for a project (not out of choice) and have come across a problem regarding the pressing of multiple keys at once. In the `keyPressed()`function, I have multiple conditionals, each mapping a key to an action. This is all well and good, but supposing I want to press multiple keys at once?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array. Assign a numeric value to each key that you are checking, then turn on the corresponding value in the array on or off whenever a key is pressed or released. Then in the draw() you check the values of the array to see which are on and off at any given instant.

```
boolean[] keys = new boolean[4];
final int A = 0;
final int D = 1;
final int W = 2;
final int S = 3;

void setup() {

}

void draw() {

 if (keys[D]) {
   // do something;
 } 
if (keys[A]) {
   // do something;
 } 
if (keys[W]) {
   // do something;
 } 
if (keys[S]) {
   // do something;
 } 

} // end of draw()


void keyPressed() {
   int mybutton = key;  // the ascii value of the key that was pushed

     switch (mybutton) {
      case 101: 
        keys[D] = true;
        break;
      case 97: 
        keys[A] = true;
        break;
      case 44:
        keys[W] = true;
        break;
      case 111:
        keys[S] = true;
        break;
    } // end switch

} // end keyPressed

void keyReleased() {
switch (mybutton) {
      case 101: 
        keys[D] = false;
        break;
      case 97: 
        keys[A] = false;
        break;
      case 44:
        keys[W] = false;
        break;
      case 111:
        keys[S] = false;
        break;
    } // end switch

} // end keyReleased
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the keydown event and push every keys in a list (array, stack, etc.) then clear it on the keyreleased. The keydown is fired at the moment that the key gets down, so if you compare the list to the one you expect, it will do the trick. Something like :

```
var arrKeys = [];

function zone_keyDown(event) {
   var evt = window.event || event;
   arrKeys.push(evt.keyCode);
}

function zone_keyReleased(event) {
   arrKeys = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using keyPressed() by itself, you could use keyPressed() and keyReleased() and keep track of what keys are down and only perform actions during keyReleased().